# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when connecting Visual Studio 2017 to Gitlab Project

Tags: git, connection, visual-studio, gitlab

I reinstalled the Git and now when I want to connect to my gitlab project from Visual Studio 2017 and open the synchronization tab , it stops working and shows this error in the team explorer:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException`

Then Visual Studio gets restarted. 
This is the script of the Error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=
  StackTrace:
   at GitLab.VisualStudio.Services.GitAnalysis.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at GitLab.VisualStudio.Services.GitAnalysis.Finalize()

Comment: Check event viewer app logs and see if it gives more verbose detail of the `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` and if so, [edit] this post and include those details "on your question". Simply [edit] and add the detail there if there is any that you find. Check system logs as well if you don't see anything relevant in the app logs around the time the error occurred.

Comment: Two resources I want to leave you with to read over and see if anything that anyone mentions in any of the posts relate to your problem and could be potentially helpful. Read all comments, threads, etc. until you see something that you feel may be relevant. . . `1.` https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/1812 and `2.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979136/visual-studio-2017-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-io-filesystem